# How to communicate to Coq that certain types are equal?

Tags: coq, dependent-type, convoy-pattern

I have a heterogenous list as described in CPDT:

```
Section hlist.
  Variable A : Type.
  Variable B : A -> Type.
  Inductive hlist : list A -> Type :=
  | HNil : hlist nil
  | HCons : forall (x : A) (ls : list A), B x -> hlist ls -> hlist (x :: ls)
  .
End hlist.
```

and am trying to define a 'pointwise membership' predicate between a list of `Ensemble`s and a list of elements:

```
Definition hlist_in_ensemble_hlist {A : Type}{B : A -> Type}(types : list A)
           (sets : hlist A (fun a => Ensemble (B a)) types) (elems : hlist A B types) : Prop :=
  match sets with
  | HNil _ _ => True
  | HCons _ _ a1 a1s b1 b1s =>
    match elems with
    | HNil _ _ => False
    | HCons _ _ a2 a2s b2 b2s =>
      Ensembles.In (B a1) b1 b2 (* /\ recursion (TODO) *)
    end
  end.
```

However, Coq complains about the `Ensembles.In (B a1) b1 b2` part:

```
The term "b2" has type "B a2" while it is expected to have type "B a1"
```

Intuitively, `a1` and `a2` are the same, since they are the heads of the same `types` list. How do I communicate that to Coq? I tried matching `elems` with `cons x xs` and changing the offending line to `Ensembles.In (B x) b1 b2`, but that results in a similar error. I also read about the Convoy pattern, but am not sure how to apply it in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic application of the *convoy pattern* of CPDT: when you need to argue that two indices are equal after pattern matching, you need to change the match so that it returns a function. In this case, I find it easier to perform the recursion on the `hlist` indices:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Section hlist.
  Variable A : Type.
  Variable B : A -> Type.
  Inductive hlist : list A -> Type :=
  | HNil : hlist nil
  | HCons : forall (x : A) (ls : list A), B x -> hlist ls -> hlist (x :: ls)
  .
  Definition head x xs (l : hlist (x :: xs)) : B x :=
    match l with
    | HCons _ _ b _ => b
    end.

  Definition tail x xs (l : hlist (x :: xs)) : hlist xs :=
    match l with
    | HCons _ _ _ l => l
    end.
End hlist.

Fixpoint hlist_in_ensemble_hlist {A : Type}{B : A -> Type}(types : list A)
           : hlist A (fun a => B a -> Prop) types -> hlist A B types -> Prop :=
  match types with
  | [] => fun _ _ => True
  | x :: xs => fun sets elems =>
    head _ _ _ _ sets (head _ _ _ _ elems) /\
    hlist_in_ensemble_hlist _ (tail _ _ _ _ sets) (tail _ _ _ _ elems)
  end.
```

(Note that I have inlined the definition of `Ensemble`.)